# Bash script automatic network configuration with hidden wlan

Tags: linux-networking, wifi, hidden

Hello i write a simple bash script that make the network configuration automatically. Only the last step didnt work automatically, to establish the wifi connection.
This script work simple. First it write in /etc/network/interfaces the configuration for the lan port then it write the config for wlan. The last step is to establish the connection over wlan. The wlan-AP has a hidden wlan and i cant change this.
i am thankful for every help

```
#!/bin/bash

# set static LAN IP in  /etc/network/interfaces
echo -e 'auto eth0\nallow-hotplug eth0\niface eth0 inet static\n   address 10.0.0.1\n   netmask 255.255.255.0\n' >> /etc/network/interfaces

#set wlan config in /etc/network/interfaces
echo -e 'auto wlan0\nallow-hotplug wlan0\niface wlan0 inet manual\n   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf\n' >> /etc/network/interfaces

#write wlan config in etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
echo -e 'ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev\nupdate_config=1\ncountry=DE\n\nnetwork={\n   ssid="INTERN"\n   scan_ssid=1\n   psk="password"\n   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n}\n' >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf


# restart network manager 
service network-manager restart
sleep 15
#network manager WIFI connect
nmcli device wifi connect "INTERN" password "password" hidden on
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network manager doesn't use the interfaces file. It uses own configuration files.

If you use the interfaces file, you should use the commands of the `ifupdown` package (`ifquery` to get the interface configuration, `ifup` to bring up the inteface, `ifdown` to turn off the interface). Modern implementations of the ifupdown support the `include` option, so you can store interfaces configurations in separate files under the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` directory.

If you want use the network manager to configure the network, you use the `nmcli` command. Good examples how to do it (and other things too) you can find [here](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-wifi-connections) and [here](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli-examples.html).